# NSPredicate Parsing Error

Tags: ios5, nspredicate

I have a class iVar "total" that is of type double. I would like to treat it as a string, for search purposes only, so I can use BEGINSWITH in my predicate.

What am I missing? This results in a parsing error:

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"[NSString stringWithFormat:@\"%f\",total] BEGINSWITH %@", searchText];
```

Comment: NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f BEGINSWITH %@",total] ]

Comment: Above will fix your parse errors, however I have no idea if it's going to work as a predicate :)